# How to embed python code in Jinja2 template for an image?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following code in which I'm trying to load an jpg image on a page. The image has the primary key id of a database record 1.jpg in this case. I would like to use something like {{ film.id }}.jpg. How to do that? The code below doesn't render the image.

film.id is just the primary key from the record. I want to use it as an reference index number to a corresponding image to its film. Within the tag film.id should expand to an integer. As I have only two films in the database, these should be 1 and 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MovieDB</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for film in films %}
    <p>{{ film.title }}</p>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/{{ film.id }}.jpg') }}">
{% endfor %}        
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding the example given by Alex to my views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for
from app import app
from jinja2 import filters, environment
from app.models import *


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    films = session.query(Film).all()

    return render_template('index.html', films=films)

def ufs(film_id):
    return url_for('static', filename='img/{}.jpg'.format(film_id))

app.filters['ufs'] = ufs
```

It gives the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/jwebster/Code/Python/filmdb/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/Users/jwebster/Code/Python/filmdb/app/views.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.filters['ufs'] = ufs
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'filters'
```

Comment: film.id is just the primary key from the record. I want to use it as an reference index number to a corresponding image to its film.

Comment: But you must access film variable into the `for` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a **custom filter** (and register it with Jinja2) to allow arbitrary Python code to be accessed from within Jinjia2 templates.  See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters for all details.

For example, in your Python server code, at startup:

```
def ufs(film_id):
    return url_for('static', filename='img/{}.jpg'.format(film_id))

environment.filters['ufs'] = ufs
```

where `environment` is your Jinja2 environment, and you have the `import` to make `url_for` visible as an unqualified name.

Then, in your Jinja2 template rendered from this environment,

```
{{ film.id | ufs }}
```

will expand as you require (if `film.id` is correct -- it likely would be **inside** the `for`, but you've placed it **outside**, at least in current versions of your Q, which would likely break things for other reasons).

Comment: Yes, I just figured that I could put it anywhere. Not just in the for loop.

Comment: @DarkNawg, you can put it where `film.id` is defined (I'm not sure if it is outside the `for`, but you can easily check anyway).  The core point is "how to embed arbitrary Python code" and the answer remains "put it in a custom filter, and register that filter in the environment, from the Python side; then, **use** that filter, from the template side" -- and I've shown how to do both things.

Comment: thank you for commenting. I am very new and don't have any idea where to put your example code. I've never been exposed to filters in any of the tutorials that I've studied. Can you explain where to put it? I assume in the views.py.

Comment: @DarkNawg put that code in your Python right after you build the Jinja2 environment, whether that's in `views.py` or wherever else you've chosen to do that.

Comment: I updated my post with your example code, but I'm running into a problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DarkNawg, you're for some mysterious reason trying to set `app.filters` (?) while my answer above clearly says `environment.filters` -- in other words, you're doing something very different from my suggestion, for whatever reason(s).

Comment: I did end up using your example, which needed to be modified to `app.jinja_env.filters['ufs'] = ufs`

Comment: Actually, you can just call `format` in the `url_for` call since methods are always available.  `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/{}.jpg'.format(film.id)) }}">`

Comment: @SeanVieira: Your solution is cleaner than using filters. But Alex's answer came first.

Comment: But build error:`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filters'`

Comment: @Gank, what *module* are you trying to access `filters` on? You need to use it on the *jinja2 environment* (which in `flask` is likely `app.jinja2_env`, in other frameworks will be elsewhere, but is never a **module**).